# How to turn off dynamic brightness - Ubuntu 18.04.5 - Dell G5 w/ Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, brightness

I don't know if this is software or hardware related. My screen brightness changes based on what is seen on the screen. So it fluctuates while changing window to another or scrolling up and down. This is very annoying and I would like to turn that off.

Any idea what to try? I already tried Ubuntu settings but didn't find anything that works.

Comment: That's not something available by default, so it must be something you have installed...

Answer (score 0):

That may actually be something you can switch off in your monitors' settings. I've had the same problem some years back and somebody pointed that out, which turned out to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not due to Ubuntu but due to a feature that Dell added called content-aware brightness control. There should be a BIOS setting to enable/disable this - if not, check for a BIOS update for your specific model. One other method that could help is presing F2 when powering up, then you can change the brightness in some models.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers already, but unfortunately, you may not be able to turn this feature off under Linux, or even not at all with some hardware.

This is a "feature" of specific Dell brands, where screen brightness is decreased for dark content, allowing for better differentiation (contrast) of the dark content. The feature also doubles as a power saving feature: less backlight power is used when overall screen content is darker. It is provided by specific graphics cards.

This feature obviously is a disaster, preventing photo editing work, and disrupting overall work: you scroll down, there is a dark portion of the website, or a darker figure in your document, and suddenly your screen brightness changes.

In some cases, Dell in updates provided window drivers allowing to disable the feature. Unfortunately, Linux users were left in the cold. In other cases, the hardware does not allow to turn of the feature, so disabling is not at all possible.

You may want to research the possibilities for your computer and graphics card. In the best case, there will be a possibility to turn it of provided you have Windows installed or install it just for this task. But even then, drivers that Dell provided may not anymore work on current Windows versions...